# Availability.h No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, macos, header, osx-leopard

I am trying to build a pre-written app, on OS X 10.5 with the base SDK set to OS X 10.4.
There are a couple of pre-compiled header files which are returning errors on compile, in CFNetwork.h where it is including Availability.h

"Availability.h - No such file or directory"

I checked the header path and this header is not present in the MacOSX10.4u.sdk /usr/include area.
It is present in the corresponding 10.5 SDK location.

AvailabilityInternals.h is absent as well. But AvailabilityMacros.h is present. Obviously copying these missing headers over from 10.5 location did not work.
Am I missing a package in my Leopard install that's causing this? My framework search paths seem to be ok. How to I work around this issue? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: I just looked in the CFNetwork.h in my 10.4u SDK, and it does not (directly) include Availability.h.  You didn't say what version of Xcode you're using.

Comment: But I am building this as an XCode 2.4 compatible app with 10.4 as the base sdk. Although the Deployment Target in the project settings says 10.2

Comment: Now if I can just stop pressing 'enter' after every comment :). I went ahead and copied over Availability.h and Av...Internal.h from 10.5 and recompiled. The remaining errors came from OSMessageNotificaion.h, saying 'io_user_reference_t was not declared in this scope.' and 'does not name a type'. Are these errors coming from IOKit? I do not understand how io_user_reference_t is not being declared in the header. Am I missing stuff in my base SDK? Or are some links to files missing by any chance? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/Availability.h

[image: Look in xcode]

These macros are for use in OS header files. They enable function prototypes
   and Objective-C methods to be tagged with the OS version in which they
   were first available; and, if applicable, the OS version in which they 
   became deprecated.